When can a point be reconstructed from relative angle measurements?
Given a set of points $p_1,\dots,p_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and a target point $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$, I measure all the angles between all pairs of points and the target point. In other words, I have the angles: $\theta_{ij} = \text{angle}(p_i,x,p_j)$ for all $i,j$.
Here is the problem: The points $p_1,\dots,p_n$ and all angles $\theta_{ij}$ are given. My task is to determine whether a point $x$ that is consistent with these data exists, and if so, to provide a way of constructing it. Let's assume $n \gg d$ so the problem is overdetermined.
Conjecture: I think that if I construct the matrix of angle cosines: $A_{ij} = \cos(\theta_{ij})$ then a necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of a consistent $x$ is that $A\succeq 0$ and $\text{rank}(A) \leq d$.
Necessity is easy to show, but I don't have a proof for sufficiency (or a counterexample). Here is my attempt so far at constructing $x$ from $A$. Suppose $A\succeq 0$ and $\text{rank}(A)=d$. Factor $A = H^\top H$, where $H\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times n}$. Then, if $h_i$ is the $i^\text{th}$ column of $H$, the factorization determines the unit directions up to an orthogonal transformation $U$:
$$
h_i = U \frac{p_i - x}{\|p_i-x\|}\qquad\text{for }i=1,\dots,n.
$$
But now I'm stuck. The $h_i$ and $p_i$ are known, and I have to find $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ and an orthogonal $U\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ that satisfies these equations, and I'm not sure how. Some observations:

If $U$ is known, then finding the optimal $x$ is a resection problem (construct a point from orientations with respect to known fixed reference points), and can be solved via least squares.
If $x$ is known, then finding the optimal $U$ is an orthogonal Procrustes problem (find the best way to rotate a set of vectors so it aligns with a given set of vectors), and can be solved via singular value decomposition.

But the version above is more complicated, of course, since both $U$ and $x$ are unknown.
